# page object - promise handling - error "Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined"

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am trying to click on the submit button in a login screen, only if the button text shows "Next".  In the last line below, I am getting the error - "Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined".  I think I am not resolving promise properly in the page object.  I'd appreciate it if someone could help suggest a solution..

```
//Login Page object

var LoginPage = function () {

    this.email = element(by.model('loginCtrl.username'));
    this.password = element(by.model('loginCtrl.password'));
    this.submit = element(by.css('[ng-click="loginCtrl.login()"]'));

    this.get = function(){
        browser.get('/#/login');
    };

    this.login = function () {

        this.email.clear();
        this.email.sendKeys(browser.params.login.user);

        this.submit.getText().then(function (text) {
            if (text == "Next") {
                //***ERROR below. 
                //***Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined  
                this.submit.click();
            }
    });
```

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be? Because in this case it isn't defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, when inside the `then()` function, the `this` is not pointing to your page object anymore. A common approach is to create a reference to the page object in the outer scope:

```
this.login = function () {

    this.email.clear();
    this.email.sendKeys(browser.params.login.user);

    var self = this;
    this.submit.getText().then(function (text) {
        if (text == "Next") {
            self.submit.click();
        }
     });
}
```